# SABR calibration in R. How to estimate rho and nu so sum of squared errors is minimized

Tags: programming, sabr

I start with predefined beta and alpha. Then I want to find rho and nu so the **S**um of **S**quared **E**rrors is minimized. By SSE I mean the difference between my model estimated volatilities and observed maarket volatilities. How can I do it in R?
I have done following:

```
## difvol is a function of rho and nu, which is the sum of squared errors.
nlm(difvol,0.01,0.01)
```

difvol is designed like that:

(first observed volatility - Black implied volatility)^2 + (second observed volatility - Black implied volatility)^2 ...

Black implied volatility has no values in my setup because I have no estimates for rho and nu.

However, the nlm code only returns one estimate and both I need to estimate nu and rho. What to do from here? How do I use nlm properly.

I know my difvol function could have been better but I don't want to change that.

Comment: I would say that this question belong to stackoverflow (for programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to redesign your object function, your `difvol`, so it's a function of a two dimensional vector

```
dilvol<-function(X){ 
rho<-X[1]
nu<-X[2]
##type in your function here and use rho and nu normally..
}
nlm(difvol,c(0.1,0.1)
```

This might work